# Newline in adjustbox caption

Tags: line-breaking, adjustbox

Is it possible to have a paragraph break or a newline in the caption of an adjustbox?

`\\` `\newline` and `\tabularnewline` don't seem to work. Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio,rotate=0,caption={blah \\ blah},float=table}
BLAH BLAH BLAH
    \end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not simply using a `table` environment?

Comment: Hi @egreg, in practice its a large table of data that is going in the back of a report, and is being produced from a `print(xtable(x))` command in `R-CRAN` and `knitr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the caption package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{abc\\abc}
\end{figure}

\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio,rotate=0,
caption={blah \\ blah},float=table}
BLAH BLAH BLAH
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```